# ADF : Using MSA account with Integration Runtime for On-Premise File System

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a scenario to copy data from on-premise to Cloud Storage and we are using an Integration Runtime for this.

In the Linked Service to the on-premise file system, I see an option for providing username/password, or to retrieve the same from a key vault. However, want to know if I will be able to use a MSA/gMSA account to connect to the on-premise file system, so that I do not have the hassle of managing passwords.

Any quick pointers on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your MSA/gMSA account can access the local machine then you can.
As the [Azure Data Factory doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system) defines:

[image]
[image]

---

**Update:**
You can choose to use Key Vault to store your password, so that you don't need to enter the password any more. You can manage the password centrally.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the details... however, the linked service is expecting a password.

Comment: You can choose Azure Key Vault to store the password in the secret. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else looking into this, it turns out that this is not currently supported, and a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/bb9eaa3d-7226-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) for this was created in 2020 in response to [the OPs request on the MS Learn site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/66094/using-msa-account-with-integration-runtime-for-on).